# Move an element in the list to the first position using Stream

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have written this piece of code and I would like to convert it to `stream` and while keeping the same behavior.

```
List<String> str1 = new ArrayList<String>();
str1.add("A");
str1.add("B");
str1.add("C");
str1.add("D");

int index = str1.indexOf("C");

if ((str1.contains("C")) && (index != 0)) {
    str1.remove("C");
    str1.add(0, "C");
}
```

Comment: What you have written is already efficient. Also, this is not the right example for the usage of streams.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: is there an `else` part to the above as well? are you looking for any specific ordering?

Answer (score 3):

You could simplify:

```
int index = str1.indexOf("C");

if ((str1.contains("C")) && (index != 0)) {
    str1.remove("C");
    str1.add(0, "C");
}
```

as

```
if (str1.remove("C")) { 
    str1.add(0, "C"); 
}
```

(Check the javadoc for `remove(Object)`.  It removes the first instance of the object that it finds, and returns `true` if an object was removed.  There is no need to find and test the object's index.)

At this point, you should probably stop.

- A small gotcha is that if `"C"` is the first element, you are removing it and adding it again ... unnecessarily.  You could deal with this as follows:

  ```
  int index = str1.index("C");
  if (index > 1) {
      str1.add(0, str1.remove(index));
  }
  ```
- You could optimize further to avoid the double copying of a remove and an add.  For example (thanks to @Holger):

  ```
  Collections.rotate(str1.subList(0, str1.indexOf("C") + 1), 1);
  ```

  (But if you say that is simple, a regular Java programmer will probably throw something at you.  It requires careful reading of the javadocs to understand that this is actually efficient.)
- You *could* rewrite this as 2 stream operations but there is no point doing it.  Both operations (remove first and insert into stream) are inefficient and tricky to implement.  Tricky to implement means hard to read.

Note: Using streams to solve every problem is not a sensible goal.  The *main point* of streams is to express complex transformations in a way that is easier to read and maintain than conventional loops.  If the only stream-based solutions to a problem are actually *harder* to read and maintain than the non-stream solutions, that is clear evidence that you shouldn't be trying to use streams to solve *that* problem!

---

Note that the above solutions are for the problem *as stated*.  However if object identity for the elements actually matters, the only one of the solutions above that actually *moves* an object to the start of the list is the solution that uses `rotate`.

Comment: The alternative would be `int index = str1.indexOf("C"); if(index > 0) str1.add(0, str1.remove(index));` That would void actions when the element is already the first and further retain the object identity of the contained element, for cases where it matters. Avoiding the double copying is not so hard. The statement is `Collections.rotate(str1.subList(0, str1.indexOf("C")+1), 1);` which does already handle the cases that the element is at the first position or absent.